# NetBeans 5.5.1 Webstart RMI client can't connect after Java Update 25

Tags: java, netbeans, rmi, platform, java-web-start

Having called into the NetBeans library with :-

```
try {
        Object[] argss = new String[] {"--branding", "assetwatch_platform"};
        Class c = loader.loadClass("org.netbeans.Main");
        Method m = c.getMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
        m.invoke(null, new Object[] {argss});
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

NetBeans creates the platform window but fails to pass control onto user code and cannot connect over the RMI port 80. There is nothing in the webstart client logs. I have read all the questions about the class loader and have applied the workarounds to no effect. I have tried getting hold of the source for 5.5.1 but the CVS server no longer responds. Any ideas?

Comment: Err, ***upgrade?*** I stopped using NetBeans 5.5.1 about ten years ago, and I was slow. Why are you still using it?

Comment: Thanks. I've inherited this million line ball of mud and have not had the opportunity.... yet. The prevailing attitude has been "if it ain't broke"; Now it is broke and upgrading may be the only fix

Answer (score 0):

I 'bit-the-bullet' and used the ant build here [Netbeans platform][1]https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-ant.html#rcp to get the latest platform. After some 'frigging in the rigging'  the web-start application was resurrected with very little change to the source or the application. This has to be testament to the quality of the NetBeans framework. The Web Browser module is still not adequate for modern webapps and I have to find a way of disabling modules but generally a cloud has lifted from above me.